# Embedding IPTC to Image in PHP with GD

Tags: php, iptc

I am trying to take a photograph and create a thumbnail without losing the IPTC info that contains copyright info and other information. I am scripting using GD for the resize which of course results in the loss of the IPTC data since it creates an entire new file, not actually resizing the original. So, my solution was to extract the IPTC data from the original image and then embed it in the thumbnail. As of now, everything runs fine and the thumbnail is generated except the IPTC data is not copied over. My code snippet is below. Can anyone see anyhting I am missing? This is based off of the examples in the PHP manual for iptcembed(). Oh yeah, I am working within the Zend Framework but apart from the Registry to handle the config, this is pretty straightforward OOP code. Thanks!

```
        public function resizeImage($image, $size)
    {
            // Get Registry
            $galleryConfig = Zend_Registry::get('gallery_config');

            $path = APPLICATION_PATH . $galleryConfig->paths->mediaPath . $image->path . '/';
            $file = $image->filename . '.' . $image->extension;
            $newFilename = $image->filename . '_' . $size . '.' . $image->extension;

            // Get Original Size
            list($width, $height) = getimagesize($path . $file);

            // Check orientation, create scalar
            if($width > $height){
                    $scale = $width / $size;
            }else{
                    $scale = $height / $size;
            }

            // Set Quality
            switch($size){
                    case ($size <= 200):
                            $quality = 60;
                            break;
                    case ($size > 200 && $size <= 600):
                            $quality = 80;
                            break;
                    case ($size > 600):
                            $quality = 100;
                            break;
            }

            // Recalculate new sizes with default ratio
            $new_width = round($width * (1 / $scale));
            $new_height = round($height * (1/ $scale));

            // Resize Original Image
            $imageResized = imagecreatetruecolor($new_width, $new_height);
            $imageTmp     = imagecreatefromjpeg ($path.$file);
            imagecopyresampled($imageResized, $imageTmp, 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $width, $height);

            // Save File
            $complete = imagejpeg($imageResized, $path . $newFilename, $quality);

            // Copy IPTC info into new file
            $imagesize = getImageSize($path . $file, $info); 
            if(isset($info['APP13'])){ 
            $content = iptcembed($info['APP13'], $path . $newFilename); 
               $fw = fopen($path . $newFilename , 'wb'); 
               fwrite($fw, $content); 
               fclose($fw); 
            }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think iptcembed does automatically save the file, which means that the php.net manual example is wrong:

> Return Values
>   If success and spool flag is lower than 2 then the JPEG will not be returned as a string, FALSE on errors.

See http://php.net/iptcembed